# How many possibilities to arrange N blocks (or less) in L slots

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Given $N$ blocks (numbered $1$ to $N$) and an array with $L$ slots, $N > L$, I need to find out how many possibilities are there to arrange the blocks in the array without repeating any block. The slots in the array can also be empty - in this case they will be labeled $0$.

For example for $N=7$ and $L=5$ some valid combinations are $[4,7,2,5,1]$, $[1,0,0,7,3]$ or $[1,7,3,0,0]$ but not $[1, 4, 4, 5, 6]$.

I came up with the following result $$\sum^L_{k=0} P(N,L-k)C(L,k)$$
Where P(,) denotes permutation and C(,) combinations.

Is this correct? Does this simplify to a more concise formula?

**Edit**: If a concise formula is not available is it possible to find a lower bound to the result of the exponential form? i.e. $L^x$ or $N^x$

Comment: I don't think there's a pleasant form. [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5Bk%21*BinomialCoefficient%5Bn%2Ck%5D*BinomialCoefficient%5Bm%2Ck%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cn%7D%5D) identifies the sum as a value of a [confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) if that helps.

Comment: @lulu thanks for your comment. I edited the question in order to get something I can use.

Comment: From [This page](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.8) we can find the asymptotic expansion for $U(a,b,z)$

Comment: @FFjet I don't really know how to use those expansions. Can you help?

Comment: Your formula is absolutely correct, however I doubt there's a closed formula for that sum